# How do I avoid foreign key constraint fail error -

Tags: mysql, dreamweaver

I am currently using dreamweaver and I am trying to insert a record insertion wizard connected to a mysql server. However when I try to update the column I get a foreign key constraint fail and I can understand this is due to me creating a non existent foreign key.But how else can I use an input wizard.

[database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0L6Af.png)

Here is the data model. 
The column I am trying to update is "kommentar" but it is not working, any ideas?

Comment: What does this error actually look like?  what FK relationship are you actually trying to make?  from what table to what table?...Some more info is needed here in order to give a solid answer....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tough to say with the info provided, but in all likelihood the value you're using in hotellid doesn't have a corresponding entry in the table hotell.

Comment: Yeah, the corresponding entry is non existent but is there a way to make this work by creating the hotelid the moment you use the insert wizard?
Thanks

Comment: Yes, if you use the wizard to first create an entry in the hotell table.  Then with the new hotellid, you should be able to add your initial row.

Answer (score 0):

You could run the same wizard for the hotels and add a hotel with your desired hotelid, **before** inserting into `kommentar`